# Combobox "Select Item" binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, combobox

I'm working on a few ComboBoxes that need a "select" property as the top option in WPF (c#)

At the moment I have the combobox's named and then populated in the code behind from a array string.

```
<ComboBox Width="150" x:Name="cmbTitle" Margin="3" SelectedIndex="0" />
```

.

```
cmbTitle.Items.Add("Select");
foreach (var title in Constants.Title)
            cmbTitle.Items.Add(title);
```

My Issue is that the selectd Index will always be off by 1 of the index in the string.

After doing my research I see that this is a very prehistoric way of populating a combo box (WinFrom background). Constants seem to be stored in Enums in every example I have looked at so would like to move away from multiple string[]s.

What is my best way of binding an enum to a combobox while accommodating for a "select" option in WPF?
I've looked at half a dozen options today and I'm not too sure what other code examples to list.

It's quite a open question, but I'm quite lost.

Thanks in advance,
Oli

Comment: Should the "Select" option be available for picking, or it's just a prompt for users? If latter, there's [a better way of doing that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901536/can-a-wpf-combobox-display-alternative-text-when-its-selection-is-null).

Comment: @Joulukuusi It should just be a prompt for the user. Thanks, this looks very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Values of an enumeration can be retrieved from [`Enum.GetValues()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx), and binding to a method is typically done using `ObjectDataProvider`. Here's an example of getting all `BindingMode` values:

   ```
   <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="BindingModes" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}" MethodName="GetValues">
       <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
           <x:Type TypeName="BindingMode" />
       </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
   </ObjectDataProvider>
   ```

   Now, we can bind `ItemsSource` of our `ComboBox`:

   ```
   <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource BindingModes}}" />
   ```
2. Our control needs a new property for the prompt:

   ```
   public class ExtendedComboBox : ComboBox
   {
       public static readonly DependencyProperty PromptProperty =
           DependencyProperty.Register("Prompt", typeof(string), typeof(ExtendedComboBox), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

       public string Prompt
       {
           get { return (string)GetValue(PromptTextProperty); }
           set { SetValue(PromptTextProperty, value); }
       }
   }
   ```

   We can cheat a bit and place a `TextBlock` with the prompt inside our control, and hide it when there's an item selected. For this we rewrite `ControlTemplate` of the control with a new one containing the `TextBlock`. I modified template from [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5728508/577167):

   ```
   <Style x:Key="PromptTextBlock" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" >
       <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
       <Style.Triggers>
           <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Value="{x:Null}">
               <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
           </DataTrigger>
       </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>

   <Style x:Key="PromptedComboBox" TargetType="{x:Type local:ExtendedComboBox}">
       <Setter Property="Template">
           <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ExtendedComboBox}">
                   <Grid>
                       <ToggleButton x:Name="DropDownToggle"
                                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  
                                     Margin="-1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
                                     IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                           <Path x:Name="BtnArrow" Height="4" Width="8" 
                                 Stretch="Uniform" Margin="0,0,4,0"  Fill="Black"
                                 Data="F1 M 300,-190L 310,-190L 305,-183L 301,-190 Z " />
                       </ToggleButton>
                       <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" Margin="6,2,25,2"
                                         Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                                         ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                                         ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}">
                       </ContentPresenter>
                       <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                                Style="{x:Null}"
                                Focusable="False"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                Margin="3,3,23,3"
                                Visibility="Hidden"
                                IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"/>
                           <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}">
                               <Border x:Name="PopupBorder" 
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" 
                                       MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                                       MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}"
                                       BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                                       BorderBrush="Black" Background="White" CornerRadius="3">
                                   <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" BorderThickness="0" Padding="1">
                                       <ItemsPresenter/>
                                   </ScrollViewer>
                               </Border>
                           </Popup>
                       <TextBlock Margin="4,3,20,3" Text="{Binding PromptText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Style="{StaticResource PromptTextBlock}"/>
                   </Grid>
               </ControlTemplate>
           </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
   ```
3. Combining, we have:

   ```
   <local:ExtendedComboBox Style="{StaticResource PromptedComboBox}" Prompt="Select an item" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource BindingModes}}" />
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to populate your ComboBox will be using IDictionary.

As an example, your code-behind:

```
public YourEnum SelectedOption { get; set; }

public IDictionary<string, YourEnum> Options = new Dictionary<string, YourEnum?>();

Options.Add("Select", null);
Options.Add("Option 1", YourEnum.Option1);
...
Options.Add("Option N", YourEnum.OptionN);
```

Your xaml file:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Options, ...}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedOption, ...}" DisplayMemberPath="Key" SelectedValuePath="Value" />
```